# ReturnType not working when creating mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I'm trying to build a system to have enhanced typedefs with validations.

```
export interface Struct {
  [key: string]: <T>(input: string) => T | DiplomacyError;
}
export type RawType<T extends Struct> = {
  [Property in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[Property]>;
};
const Person = {
  age: all<number>(isInteger, isNonNegative),
  name: all<string>(isString, matchesPattern(/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/)),
};
type RawPerson = RawType<typeof Person>;
```

Why isn't the `type RawPerson` equal to `{ age: number | DiplomacyError, name: string | DiplomacyError }` as I was expecting?

It comes out as  `type RawPerson = { age: unknown, name: unknown }`, instead.

See the `all` function:

```
/**
 * @param typifier Determines the raw type.
 * @param assertions Predicates the value needs to "pass".
 * @returns Either "Cannot Decode" or the casted value.
 */
export const all = <T>(typifier: Typifier<T>, ...assertions: Assertor[]) => <T>(
  input: string
): T | DiplomacyError => {
  const parsedInput = typifier(input);

  if (parsedInput === "#!CD") {
    return "#!CD" as DiplomacyError;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < assertions.length; i++) {
    if (assertions[i](parsedInput) === "#!CD") {
      return "#!CD" as DiplomacyError;
    }
  }

  return (parsedInput as unknown) as T;
};
```

Comment: Try removing the explicit declaration of Person as Struct so that Typescript infer it by the object literal.

Comment: One step forward, but I get `unknown`, see the updated question

Comment: I'm afraid `ReturnType` might just not work when creating mapped types?

Comment: Can you add the all function you use?

Comment: IIRC `ReturnType` doesn't work too well with generic function types, like `<T>(input: string) => T | DiplomacyError`.

Comment: So I guess no workaround for this?